# Isekai manga about a main character who uses math and numbers to cast magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character was in a research group on Earth and could use magic before being transported to another world. He tried to hide his powers in the isekai world, but was revealed after someone attacked him (it's been a few years since I read it so I'm not sure). He came with other people and was mainly a black and white manga

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Do you recall if he went to the other world by himself or with others?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the "math and numbers" tie in to the magic? Does he need to do explicit calculations to accomplish anything? Or are there just a bunch of numbers and mathematical symbols in the background acting like a magical circle? Or does he just namedrop "complex numbers" at one point while talking about barriers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very possible to be Isekai Mahou wa okureteru!

The main character, [Suimei](https://isekai-no-mahou-wa-okureteru.fandom.com/wiki/Suimei_Yakagi), is a magician from our world who uses mostly math in its formulas and magic circles unlike the new worlds magic that is based in the 4 main elements.

He gets attacked early on and needs to unleash his magic at the woman who summoned him, together with his two friends, one of them being the Hero.

Comment: that is the manga i was looking for thanks for helping aaaa

Comment: @arandomcake If this answer is correct, could you click the green check mark next to it? That will help anyone else who is looking for this same manga.